# How to control #id link on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tdz3H/) will explain more than my words

How to avoid hidden Title when click on **Link id 2**, **Link id 3** and **Link id 4**?

PS: Please if anyone have a better Name for this question, please help, my English is not that good!

```
<header id="header">
   header
</header>

<div class="catalog">
    <div class="col1">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#id1">Link id 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id2">Link id 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id3">Link id 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id4">Link id 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id5">Link id 5</a></li>

       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col_alternativ"></div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div id="id1" class="item">
            <h2>Link id 1</h2>            
        </div>
        <div id="id2" class="item">
            <h2>Link id 2</h2>            
        </div>
        <div id="id3" class="item">
            <h2>Link id 3</h2>            
        </div>
        <div id="id4" class="item">
            <h2>Link id 4</h2>            
        </div>
        <div id="id5" class="item">
            <h2>Link id 5</h2>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(window).scroll(function() {    
                var newValue = {opacity : 100}
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                if (scroll >= 100) {
                    $("#header").addClass("stablemenu").animate(newValue, 1000);
                    $(".col1").addClass("stable_col1").animate(newValue, 1000);
                    $(".col_alternativ").css({"display":"inline-block"});
                } else {
                    $("#header").removeClass("stablemenu");
                    $(".col1").removeClass("stable_col1").animate(newValue, 1000);
                    $(".col_alternativ").css({"display":"none"});
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the `id` on the `H2`?

Comment: yes i did try to call on H2... no luck

Comment: Easiest way is to the top of each `.item` 100px to allow for the height of the header.

Comment: @Blazemonger I think you are talking about this option: http://jsfiddle.net/tdz3H/3/ this one I made, as a solution. However it looks a bit not proffesional... I have added a ABSOLUTE position div inside each .item, and asigned to it -100px top...

Comment: There's some more CSS involved to make it look good, true. But clearly your fiddle doesn't resemble your final site, so I left it to you to work out how to tweak it. There are JavaScript solutions, too, but I think the `padding-top:100px;` fix is ultimately the simplest.

Comment: @Blazemonger - Do you mean to add "padding-top:100px;" for each itme?

Comment: @Andrei, yes I think he did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do what you wanted... I think.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/tdz3H/8/

**Edit: Here's the code**

```
<header id="header">
   header
</header>

<div class="catalog">
    <div class="col1">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#id1">Link id 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id2">Link id 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id3">Link id 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id4">Link id 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#id5">Link id 5</a></li>

       </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col_alternativ"></div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="item">
            <div id="id1" class="hederid"></div>
            <h2>Link id 1</h2>            
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div id="id2" class="hederid"></div>
            <h2>Link id 2</h2>            
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div id="id3" class="hederid"></div>
            <h2 id="id3">Link id 3</h2>            
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div id="id4" class="hederid"></div>
            <h2>Link id 4</h2>            
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div id="id5" class="hederid"></div>
            <h2>Link id 5</h2>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.stablemenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
.catalog {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.catalog .col1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.catalog .col_alternativ {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    display: none;
}
.stable_col1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 140px;
    left: 0px;
}
.catalog .col2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.item {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: auto;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
.item .hederid {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    top: -140px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var newValue = {opacity : 100}
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 100) {
        $("#header").addClass("stablemenu").animate(newValue, 1000);
        $(".col1").addClass("stable_col1").animate(newValue, 1000);
        $(".col_alternativ").css({"display":"inline-block"});
        $('.col2').css('margin-top','100px');
        //$("#topbar").show().animate(newValue, 1000);
    } else {
        $("#header").removeClass("stablemenu");
        $(".col1").removeClass("stable_col1").animate(newValue, 1000);
        $(".col_alternativ").css({"display":"none"});
        $('.col2').css('margin-top','0');
    }
});
```

Comment: Really? Looks great to me in Chrome.

Comment: Ahh, ok I see what you mean.

Comment: Sorry. On second thought, I don't think I can do what you're asking.  I'm not sure what you want is possible in current HTML/CSS.  Bootstrap has the fixed-header display as a documented pattern but even their fixed header overlaps target anchors: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/945cy/1/

Comment: I supposed you could use an `<iframe></iframe>` if you really needed this behavior.  Of course then you have the problem of giving the iframe a fixed height; it would look too big on some screens, too large on others.  Best of luck on finding a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your try, maybe you can help me with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/tdz3H/3/  this is my solution, however it works only after 2nd click (even on the same link) well, how to make it work even after 1st click? Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, ok. What did you change?

Comment: I added for each .item "possition: relative", and I have added inside each .item a div with absolute possition. and assigned to it a top: -140px; the ID is attached to this div

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/tdz3H/8/.  There, I add/remove a 100px margin to `.col2`.  Looks OK. Does that help?

Comment: I updated this answer with the most recent code/fiddle.  Glad we arrived at a solution together!